# awk scripting for simulation

Tags: awk

hai friends good evening to all
i am the beginner to awk so i request you to please help me 
i want to print total number of records(rows) in a text file.for that i use "print NR "command.when i use this command on BEGIN block it prints number of records instead of printing total.but when we use it in END block it returns total number of records.
for example i have a text file with 5 column and i tried like this
BEGIN {
print NR
} it returns 
1
2
3
4
5

i want to print total number of records(rows) from BEGIN block itself,so please give me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NR is populated/incremented as the files are read, BEGIN is executed before any file is opened, so what you're specifically asking for can't be done.

A workaround is this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ while ( (getline var < ARGV[1] > 0) ) nr++; print nr }' file
```

but on UNIX there are simpler ways if your records are newline-separated, e.g.:

```
awk -v nr="$(wc -l < file)" 'BEGIN{ print nr }' file
```

Also just in awk you could probably get the output you want using:

```
awk 'NR!=FNR && FNR==1 { print NR - FNR }' file file
```

Comment: and one more doubt is what is -v in second example

Comment: how to over write into a text file using awk program
for example i have a text file with 3 columns and 3 rows.now i want to add one more column in to that file.please tell me the awk script for this process.

Comment: ARGV is the array of arguments past to awk so ARGV[1] is the first argument which is the file name. -v is the option you use to set variables to values before the awk script runs. awk is a tool for parsing text files. shell is a tool for manipulating files and processes. So, to update a file you use both: `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 1):

`BEGIN` block will be executed before starting the file processing line by line.
so you cannot get the total records in `BEGIN` block.

it has to be done in some odd way like below:

```
awk 'BEGIN{"wc -l "FILENAME|getline result;print result}' your_file
```

here the above literally means that awk is doing nothing.its actually the shell which is doing most of the thing.

Comment: The above will include the file name in the output and rather than have shell call awk to call shell to call wc, it's better to simply have shell call wc and then call awk.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass a variable in order to access the number of records/lines in the `BEGIN` block, because the `BEGIN` block is executed before the file is processed:

```
awk -v count="$(wc -l < file.txt)" 'BEGIN { print count }' file.txt
```